# Operator ' ' cannot be applied to operand of type <int> and null

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have the below method that accepts `BuildAppStat` object as parameter.
However it can be null sometimes.

So I am calling it like as :

```
sourceId: bas.BuildAppStatId ?? null
```

and getting compile error

> operator ' ' cannot be applied to operand of type `<int>` and `null`.

How can I fix this?

```
public PageBuildVrsn EditPageBuildVrsn(string caption, string nameInUse, string description, BuildAppStat bas = null, int pageBuildVrsnTypeId = 1)
{
    PageBuildVrsn pbv = Create(pageBuildVrsnTypeId, caption, nameInUse, description);
    pbv.ParentBuildAppStats = new List<BuildAppStat>();
    pbv.ParentBuildAppStats.Add(
        BasFactory.Create(
            DateTimeOffset.Now,
            true,
            sourceId: bas.BuildAppStatId ?? null
        )
    );

    return pbv;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `bas.BuildAppStatId`? It sounds like it's `int`.

Comment: yes it is int. a nullable int column in database. if there is no value we will leave it as null in database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use the null-coalescing operator with a first operand which is a nullable type (either a nullable value type, or any reference type). It sounds like `bas.BuildAppStatId` is just an `int`, which means you can't use the null-coalescing operator with it.

If you were trying to guard against `bas` itself being null, you want:

```
sourceId: bas == null ? (int?) null : bas.BuildAppStatId,
```

Answer (score 1):

BuildAppStatId should be declared as a nullable int.

```
int?
```

then if you have trouble with "?? null", use either

```
... ?? null as int?
```

or

```
... ?? default(int?)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`?? Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

> The **??** operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for **nullable value types** or **reference types**.

Since your `bas.BuildAppStatId` is an `int`, you can't use `??` in here.